# How i can show last index Array to first index

Tags: arrays, swift

I have a stupid problem.

```
var array1 = ["a","b","c","d"]
```

I want to show it start last index to first for example

```
// d , c , b , a
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

that's an array.  there's a reverse method on arrays.

You should definitely consult a Swift reference while you're coding. Apple has a free one. [Swift Manual](https://itunes.apple.com/us/book/the-swift-programming-language-swift-3-1/id881256329?mt=11)

```
var a = [1, 1, 3, 4, 5]

let b = a.reversed()
a.reverse()
```

at this point, a and b are both: [5, 4, 3, 1, 1]

You can also type the array name, followed by a dot

```
array.
```

the IDE will prompt you with all the possibilities you have to alter the array. reverse and reversed are just two of them.

Once you settle on an option, try option-click on your selection, and you'll see a full description:

mutating func reverse()

Description
Reverses the elements of the collection in place.
The following example reverses the elements of an array of characters:

```
var characters: [Character] = ["C", "a", "f", "é"]
characters.reverse()
print(cafe.characters)
// Prints "["é", "f", "a", "C"]
```

Complexity

O(n), where n is the number of elements in the collection.

That's a lot of useful information!

Answer (score 1):

```
let numbers = [3, 5, 7]
for number in numbers.reversed() {
    print(number)
}
```

Take a look at Apple's [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/1690025-reversed) on that.

Comment: @Abdul-Hameed Thanks !!!